# (Compose MD3) How do maintain shadow of Elevated Button when changing its content color?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Material Design 3 and trying to make an Elevated Button with Compose.

I've noticed when I try to set a color on my Elevated Button, it fails to have any shadow.

```
@Composable
fun PrimaryButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @StringRes text: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(
            defaultElevation = 2.dp,
            pressedElevation = 2.dp,
            focusedElevation = 2.dp,
            hoveredElevation = 2.dp,
            disabledElevation = 0.dp
        ),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(
            containerColor = Color(0xFFC34E69)
        ),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(text),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
            color = White
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

However, when you do not specify a color and let it use the default `MaterialTheme.Surface`.

```
@Composable
fun PrimaryButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @StringRes text: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(
            defaultElevation = 2.dp,
            pressedElevation = 2.dp,
            focusedElevation = 2.dp,
            hoveredElevation = 2.dp,
            disabledElevation = 0.dp
        ),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(text),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
            color = White
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

It seems like lighter colors work vs darker ones. Just substituting my original button color to a lighter color seems to work.

Is there a work around to make the elevated shadow border more prominent with original my pink colour? Increasing the button elevation doesn't have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're on an old version of material 3? I tested your code using library version 1.1.0-alpha06 and the shadow appears.

Comment: I'm using the latest stable verison 1.0.1. I just tried 1.1.0-alpha06 and it looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface.copy(alpha = 0.99f) for containerColor